# Dynamically add HTML5 input attributes from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

I'm trying to populate new HTML5 input attribute values into a Razor partial view. My model looks like this:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    public int? Columns { get; set; }
    public int? Maximum { get; set; }
    public string Placeholder { get; set; }
}
```

My partial view looks like this:

```
@model Answer
@{Layout = null;}

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AnswerText, new { @class="textbox", cols="@Model.Columns", max="@Model.Maximum", placeholder="@Model.Placeholder" })
```

Probably unsurprisingly this generates html that looks like this (I've left out some irrelevant attributes):

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" cols="@Model.Columns", max="@Model.Maximum", placeholder="@Model.Placeholder">
```

Whereas what I'm after is html that looks like this, but with whatever value happpens to be in the model:

```
 <input type="text" class="textbox" cols="50", max="30", placeholder="Answer here">
```

I'm sure this is me having a Homer Simpson moment but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the quotes and use GetValueOrDefault on the nullable fields:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AnswerText, new { @class="textbox", cols=Model.Columns.GetValueOrDefault(), max=Model.Maximum.GetValueOrDefault(), placeholder=Model.Placeholder })
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Garrett, but unfortunately that just generates the following html: '<input type="text" class="textbox" cols max placeholder>'

Comment: OK, it's the nullable properties that are causing the issue.  See the updated answer.  You need to use GetValueOrDefault.

Comment: After all that I realised that cols and max are only valid for textarea. The correct attributes for input type of text are size and maxlength.